# It is worth trying vs it deserves a try

Tags: meaning-in-context, construction

Let’s imagine two constructions:

> It is worth trying, and
>
> It deserves a try

Checking on google [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+worth+trying%2C+it+deserves+a+try&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20worth%20trying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20deserves%20a%20try%3B%2Cc0) I found out that both are valid English.

In my language, there are no the exact equivalents to the words *worth or to deserve*, we translate them using most frequently the word *merit* which has a similar meaning.

Now, starting from the definition of [merit](https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&ei=iONuVLWUD5faatrPgMAB#q=define+merit) as verb = to deserve or be worthy and its synonyms deserve, be worth I wonder if the above constructions convey a similar meaning and can be used interchangeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even say *it's worth a try*, which is probably the usage I personally would opt for.

There is a difference in semantics between *being worth something* and *deserving something*, but notwithstanding the semantically different “angle”, they *are* often, like in these expressions, interchangeable.

To be *worth* something means that something represents a certain value. Literally, as in *this house is worth a lot of money*, or figuratively, as in *this book is worth reading*.

It means that if you were to invest something (time, effort, money) in exchange for the object, you would have a good deal.

To *deserve* something means that something or someone has the right to receive something — either because of inherent qualities or because of a delivered good or effort. Literally, as in *an employee deserves to be paid for doing their work* or figuratively as in *this book deserves reading*.

As you noticed, when I am talking about a good book, I can use both options without any problem. For some people, there might be a small perceived difference in meaning, but I dare say that in general, both options will be interpreted the same.

On the other hand, these examples would *not* sit well with most people:

> This house deserves a lot of money.

It raises the question what the house *did* to "deserve" money. The sentence indicates I should give money to the house, not to buy it, but because somehow the house deserves to be donated funds.

> An employee is worth money for their job.

This treats the employee as a commodity, that can be bought!

In general, *deserve* indicates some (moral) right to something, whereas *worth* indicates a real of figurative *value*.

> Crime deserves punishment. *(not is worth punishment!)*
>   This painting is worth a fortune. *(not deserves a fortune!)*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're interchangeable.

As an aside: The closest common phrase involving *merit* I can come up with is *it merits consideration*, which is similar but not exactly interchangeable with the above two. (There's also *it merits a go*, which is closer in meaning, but this sounds British and is much more colloquial than any of the others we're discussing; it doesn't show up in the Ngram viewer.)

Comment: Much obliged, especially for the use of merit! +1